# android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity while using FragmentManager in Recycler Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have Recycler Adapter class and implemented the `setOnClickListener` to replace fragment:

```
public PlacesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Place> placeList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.placeList = placeList;
}
holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFragmenLayout, new restaurantsFragment());
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "The place is tapped.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I am using API 25 and have following imports:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

The context is created as follow:

```
private Context mContext;
public PlacesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Place> placeList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.placeList = placeList;
}
```

And the adapter is instantiated as follow:

```
adapter = new PlacesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), placeList);
```

But the app crashes and returns following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to android.app.Activity

Comment: Please show how you assigned `mContext`

Comment: You used `getApplicationContext` instead of an Activity, I bet

Comment: @cricket_007 please see the updated question.

Comment: And how you made your `new PlacesAdapter`?

Comment: @cricket_007 updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Application `Context`. That is why you cannot cast that to an `Activity`.

Instead of storing Context you could store `Activity`. Or better yet, store a `WeakReference` to an `Activity`.

```
WeakReference<Activity> weakRef;

Activity activity = weakRef.get();
if(weakRef.get() != null)
{
    FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
}
```

Comment: Or better, have the adapter callback to the holding Activity instead of "reaching up" for the Fragment manager

Comment: I agree, but who knows what OP is doing in there :)